# Trying to setup a proxy via a c++ program. Doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, proxy, netsh

I am trying to set up a proxy via a c++ program but it doesn't work.
The program itself works fine but actually, it doesn't set anything.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void newproxy();

int main (){

    int ch = 0;

    cout << "Select the option:\n\n\t(1)Set a NEW proxy\n\t(2)View the current proxy settings\n\t(3)Clear ALL proxy settings\n\t(4)Exit\n\n\t";
    cin >> ch;
    cin.ignore();
    switch (ch){

        case 1 :
            system("cls");
            newproxy();
            break;

        case 2 :
            system("cls");
            system("netsh winhttp show proxy");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            main();
            break;

        case 3 :
            system("cls");
            system("netsh winhttp reset proxy");
            system("cls");
            cout << "ALL proxy settings cleared\n\n";
            main();
            break;

        case 4 :
            return 0;
            break;

    }
}

void newproxy(){

    string ip;
    string port;
    int ch = 0;

    cout << "Insert ip: ";
    getline (cin, ip);
    cout << "Inster port: ";
    getline(cin, port);
    cout << "\nAre those the correct ip and port? " << ip << ":" << port << "\n\n\t(1)Yes (2)No (3)Abort\n\n\t";
    cin >> ch;
    cin.ignore();
    switch (ch){

        case 1 :
            break;

        case 2 :
            system("cls");
            newproxy();
            break;

        case 3 : 
            system("cls");
            main();
            break;

    }
    system(("netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="+ip+":"+port).c_str());
    system("cls");
    cout << "Proxy succesfully setted\n\n";
    main();
}
```

When I set a new proxy the program actually sees it and displays it even if I restart the program, but nothing is really done. If I open the browser and search "my IP" it displays the same public IP not like when I set it up in the Windows setting.

Can someone help me?
Is the problem in the code or is it something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated: `main` and `newproxy` call `main`. Don't call `main`. Only the runtime should call `main`. If a program calls `main` you get [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB), and UB can do anything. Sometimes you get what you want. Sometimes you don't. Sometimes you do until suddenly you don't. UB is the absolute worst thing that can happen in a program. Avoid it at all costs. Instead separate the menu code out into its own function and call the menu function.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn't even notice that. Good call.

Comment: `system` has to support a large number of possible targets from bare-metal embedded systems on up. It isn't guaranteed to give any usable feedback. The commands your program issues using it could be failing hilariously and there is no way to know.  Fortunately you're using Windows and I'm pretty sure `system` on every tool chain I've used targeting Windows returns the program's exit code. Check the return code to make sure the command worked. If you're not getting a valid return code, try using `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx`, Windows system calls that may provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
 system((std::string("netsh winhttp set proxy ") + ip +":" + port).c_str());
```

You almost had it.

To use the Netsh.exe tool to configure a proxy server, follow these steps:

Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.

At the command prompt, type `netsh winhttp set proxy proxyservername:portnumber`, and then press ENTER.

Good luck.